# Kaminari How to process routes as javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an issue. I had a freelancer do some things with my code and he messed up some things. One of the main things is the pagination doesn't work. I checked my old files and it used to say this

```
Processing by HomeController#load_more_books as JS
```

Now it's giving me

```
Processing by HomeController#load_more_books as JSON
```

How do I change the processing back to Javascript? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the default format in your routes

```
get "/some-resource", to: "some_controller#some_method", defaults: {format: "js"}
```

or in you controller you can tell .json requests to respond to .js

```
#app/controllers/some_controller.rb
class SomeController
  def some_method
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render "some_js_template.js" }
    end
  end
end
```